# Failed to compile - I cant setup tailwind to run in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, compiler-errors, tailwind-css

I followed tailwind documentation to install it in react using create-react-app.
I cant find any mistakes in the instalation but i got an error when starting the app.

./node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/color/index.js 246:28
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (246:28)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

```
|     for (const [i, element] of rgb.entries()) {
|       const chan = element / 255;
>       lum[i] = chan <= 0.039_28 ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;
|     }
|
```

The node_modules/color/index.js (246:28) havent been touched and looks fine.

tailwind.confi.js and craco.config.js are exactly as tailwind documentation for react.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "2109-sailaway",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.16"
  }
}
```

Any help please

Comment: I think the problem is with using _ (underscore) for seperating number digits. try removing underscore from "0.039_28" and write it like "0.03928";